# models and belongs_to block in controllers#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been struggling with my controllers#create method for some time and remembered that I have 'belongs_to' in my product.rb, I believe the block is in some kind of validation 'belongs_to' performs when requiring @category to exist, which it does.  Somehow I am validating @product wrong. Could someone steer me in the right direction to fix this?  I can post whatever is necesssary, basically I have category belongs to user product belongs_to category, so it blocks my products#create for some reason.  Here are error messages:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `products` (`name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('btw', '2018-08-02 13:26:36', '2018-08-02 13:26:36')):
```

OMG!  THIS TOOK FOREVER.  All I had to do was add primary_key: true.  Wooo!  Thanks guys, really.

Comment: `belongs_to` by default is required, you need `belongs_to :category, optional: true` otherwise. But just if your category is actually optional it makes sense.

Comment: OK, is this standard?  Or should I be doing this the 'right' way?  Also, why isn't my foreign key, :category_id populating with data from category :id?  I added the foreign key throug add_foreign_key yet :category_id remains empty?

Comment: Is your category optional or not for your Product model?

Comment: I suppose it shouldn't be optional since category is required to create a product or have products.  I could add this into controllers but thought there would be a better way to link tables directly.

Comment: If it's not optional of course you are reveing an error in validation. It makes sense. I didn't get your question.

Comment: It would help to know what `@product.errors.full_messages` returns after the `save` fails.

Comment: The error message I am trying to avoid is that :category_id does not have a default value, so no record is created, I will edit with @product.errors.full, thx

Comment: All I want to do is add a foreign key from the category :id table - somehow it always ends up being null????

Comment: Can you add the solution as an _answer_ instead of updating your question with it? I mean for future visitors of this page.